# How to access the output of a PowerShell script?

Tags: api, delphi, powershell, delphi-xe2

How to access the output of a PowerShell script in Delphi?

I'm looking for something similar to [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but in native code.

To be more precise: I'd like to process the `PSObject` objects returned by a PowerShell invokation.

I guess since the PowerShell is written in .NET I'd have to host the .NET framework in my Delphi application?

I've seen a library called [PowerShell Objects Delphi Edition](http://www.componentsource.com/products/powershell-objects-delphi-edition/index-eur.html) on component source, but the demo doesn't support XE2 and I can't find the library on the manufaturers homepage.

**Clarification**: I'm not looking for a way to run the PowerShell, CreateProcess works fine for this.

Comment: I think you could get remObjects HYRDA to do this, but perhaps even easier would be to just write the host part in .net and then interface via TCP/IP sockets to the .net host service.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest and cleanest way to do this is with Atozed CrossTalk: http://www.atozed.com/CrossTalk/index.en.aspx

Comment: [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console-devel/?source=directory) project works fine with any console input/output even buffers, windows, mouse etc. It written on C++, but I think it can be good start point for console UI programming :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm trying CrossTalk, but it doesn't expose the `Invoke` or `EndInvoke` methods which makes it unusable. I'll ask in the Atozed newsgroup for advice.

Comment: Yes, that sounds pretty much fatal. I would hope that you'd get a helpful response from the developer.

Comment: Jens: Did you ever build such a wrapper? I would be very interested in seeing one if you did

Comment: @WarrenP I'm afraid not, it is somewhere on my very long TODO list. We settled with normal `CreateProcess` and passing data through text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a C++/CLI wrapper around System.Management.Automation.* and expose a DLL entry point like `string ExecutePowerShellScript(string script)`.  Then you should have no problem invoking that DLL entry point from Delphi.

Comment: The problem is that I'd like to process the `PSObject` objects that the `PowerShell.Invoke` method returns.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff You could create accessor functions (DLL entry points) to access the primitive info (strings, numbers, bools, etc) in the returned objects.

Comment: That'd work, but would be a lot of extra work on the C++/CLI side. I'll look into it.